# How to isolate causes for vague kernel panics?

Tags: kernel-panic

After taking a short break, I came back to my system to find it was hung hard. I had to hold the power in and upon restart, discovered the following panic... yet unlike other panics I've seen and been able to diagnose properly, this is much more vague than usual.  Any ideas here?:

```
Sat Jul  8 00:36:17 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 8 caller 0xffffff8005ffe39d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8a4bf2c1, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000001c6c9cb1c3, CR4: 0x00000000000226e0
RAX: 0xffffff8122517828, RBX: 0xfffffffffffff000, RCX: 0x0000000000001000, RDX: 0x0000000000001000
RSP: 0xffffffae8891b340, RBP: 0xffffffae8891b3d0, RSI: 0xffffff8119326580, RDI: 0xffffff80fcf0e680
R8:  0x0000000010000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff8119326580, R11: 0x0000000000000fff
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffff81224a4028
RFL: 0x0000000000010217, RIP: 0xffffff7f8a4bf2c1, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x8, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 8), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffae8891afd0 : 0xffffff8005ee953c mach_kernel : _panic + 0xec
0xffffffae8891b050 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891b230 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891b250 : 0xffffff7f8a4bf2c1 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 : __ZN23IOAccelMemoryAllocator210allocPagesEP16GLKMemoryElementyyyybj + 0x77
0xffffffae8891b3d0 : 0xffffff7f8a59d0a5 Backtrace (CPU 8), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffae8891a9a0 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae8891a9d0 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae8891aa50 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891ac30 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891ac50 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae8891ad40 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae8891ad70 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_backtrace + 0x339
0xffffffae8891af90 : 0xffffff8006003761 mach_kernel : _Debugger + 0x1a1
0xffffffae8891afd0 : 0xffffff8005ee953c mach_kernel : _panic + 0xec
0xffffffae8891b050 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891b230 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891b250 : 0xffffff7f8a4bf2c1 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 : __ZN23IOAccelMemoryAllocator210allocPagesEP16GLKMemoryElementyyyybj + 0x77
0xffffffae8891b3d0 : 0xffffff7f8a59d0a5 Backtrace (CPU 8), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffae8891a370 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae8891a3a0 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae8891a420 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891a600 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891a620 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae8891a710 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae8891a740 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_backtrace + 0x339
0xffffffae8891a960 : 0xffffff8006003761 mach_kernel : _Debugger + 0x1a1
0xffffffae8891a9a0 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae8891a9d0 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae8891aa50 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891ac30 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891ac50 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae8891ad40 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae8891ad70 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_backtrace + 0x339
0xffffffae8891af90 : 0xffffff8006003761 mach_kernel : _Debugger + 0x1a1
0xffffffae8891afd0 : 0xffffff8005ee953c mach_kernel : _panic + 0xec
0xffffffae8891b050 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891b230 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891b250 : 0xffffff7f8a4bf2c1 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 : __ZN23IOAccelMemoryAllocator210allocPagesEP16GLKMemoryElementyyyybj + 0x77
0xffffffae8891b3d0 : 0xffffff7f8a59d0a5 Backtrace (CPU 8), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffae88919d40 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae88919d70 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae88919df0 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae88919fd0 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae88919ff0 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae8891a0e0 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae8891a110 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_backtrace + 0x339
0xffffffae8891a330 : 0xffffff8006003761 mach_kernel : _Debugger + 0x1a1
0xffffffae8891a370 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae8891a3a0 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae8891a420 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891a600 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891a620 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae8891a710 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae8891a740 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_backtrace + 0x339
0xffffffae8891a960 : 0xffffff8006003761 mach_kernel : _Debugger + 0x1a1
0xffffffae8891a9a0 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae8891a9d0 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae8891aa50 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891ac30 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891ac50 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae8891ad40 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae8891ad70 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_backtrace + 0x339
0xffffffae8891af90 : 0xffffff8006003761 mach_kernel : _Debugger + 0x1a1
0xffffffae8891afd0 : 0xffffff8005ee953c mach_kernel : _panic + 0xec
0xffffffae8891b050 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891b230 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891b250 : 0xffffff7f8a4bf2c1 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 : __ZN23IOAccelMemoryAllocator210allocPagesEP16GLKMemoryElementyyyybj + 0x77
0xffffffae8891b3d0 : 0xffffff7f8a59d0a5 Backtrace (CPU 8), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffae88919710 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae88919740 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae889197c0 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae889199a0 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae889199c0 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae88919ab0 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae88919ae0 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_backtrace + 0x339
0xffffffae88919d00 : 0xffffff8006003761 mach_kernel : _Debugger + 0x1a1
0xffffffae88919d40 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae88919d70 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae88919df0 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae88919fd0 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae88919ff0 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae8891a0e0 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae8891a110 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_backtrace + 0x339
0xffffffae8891a330 : 0xffffff8006003761 mach_kernel : _Debugger + 0x1a1
0xffffffae8891a370 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae8891a3a0 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae8891a420 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891a600 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891a620 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae8891a710 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae8891a740 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_backtrace + 0x339
0xffffffae8891a960 : 0xffffff8006003761 mach_kernel : _Debugger + 0x1a1
0xffffffae8891a9a0 : 0xffffff8005ee97e0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x390
0xffffffae8891a9d0 : 0xffffff8005ee94b0 mach_kernel : _panic + 0x60
0xffffffae8891aa50 : 0xffffff8005ffe39d mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x92d
0xffffffae8891ac30 : 0xffffff8005e9a593 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xe3
0xffffffae8891ac50 : 0xffffff8006004350 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x2d0
0xffffffae8891ad40 : 0xffffff8006004101 mach_kernel : _panic_print_symbol_name + 0x81
0xffffffae8891ad70 : 0xffffff8006003f19 mach_kernel : _panic_i386_
```

Comment: Can you share more from the `.panic` file? Thanks.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin unfortunately that was it. The only thing left was a System Profile at the bottom... Thus my posting here since I've never seen a report that has been so vague...

Comment: Sure @GrahamPerrin here's that: https://cl.ly/1Y2s2c0t2s3E

Comment: Hmm, so … no list of modules, no system version and so on?

Comment: Correct... Thus you see why I used the term "vague!" :D